# Cancer imaging, clinical and genomic data request

Tags: data-request, medical

Are there other database regarding cancer imaging, clinical and genomic data except the cancer imaging archive and the GDC data portal?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new competition on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/data-science-bowl-2017)  which provides 66gb of zipped lung cancer imaging dataset.